# Grouping observations based on first row value

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
    unixtime newsess
1 1412122086       1
2 1412122130       0
3 1412122191       0
4 1412122300       0
5 1412122443       0
6 1412122090       1
7 1412122124       0
8 1412122192       0
```

And I need this:

```
    unixtime newsess  group
1 1412122086       1      1
2 1412122130       0      1
3 1412122191       0      1
4 1412122300       0      1
5 1412122443       0      1
6 1412122090       1      2
7 1412122124       0      2
8 1412122192       0      2
```

The data contains ordered timestamps of events where first event of every session is indicated by a 1. The task is to assign a unique session identifier to every event.

How to do this in R? I have googled quite a bit but seems I've hit a wall with this one.

My example data can be created with:

```
mydf <- structure(list(unixtime = c(1412122086L, 1412122130L, 1412122191L, 
       1412122300L, 1412122443L, 1412122090L, 1412122124L, 1412122192L),   
       newsess = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("unixtime", "newsess"),   
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mydf$group <- cumsum(mydf$newsess)
```