# Using R to identify and group related observations based on both logical conditions and how closely in time they occur

Tags: r

I have a dataset ("bids") that is composed of series of observations (~5 million) each of which represents a bid to purchase a product (in the simplified example below, either a book or a game). For each observation, I have (see example data below):

1. Date that the bid was submitted
2. Time that the bid was submitted
3. Name of the product on which the bidder is bidding
4. Name of the bidder

   ```
   observation date        time        product bidder
   1           1/1/2016    9:00:00 AM  book    AB
   2           1/1/2016    9:01:00 AM  book    CD
   3           1/1/2016    9:02:00 AM  book    EF
   4           1/1/2016    9:03:00 AM  book    CD
   5           1/1/2016    9:00:00 AM  game    AB
   6           1/1/2016    9:01:00 AM  game    CD
   7           1/1/2016    9:02:00 AM  game    CD
   8           1/1/2016    9:07:00 AM  game    CD
   9           1/2/2016    9:00:00 AM  book    AB
   10          1/2/2016    9:06:00 AM  book    CD
   11          1/2/2016    9:02:00 AM  book    EF
   12          1/2/2016    9:03:00 AM  book    EF
   13          1/2/2016    9:00:00 AM  game    EF
   14          1/2/2016    8:59:00 AM  game    CD
   15          1/2/2016    9:00:00 AM  game    GH
   16          1/2/2016    9:01:00 AM  game    AB
   17          1/2/2016    10:00:00 AM game    AB
   18          1/2/2016    10:06:00 AM game    CD
   19          1/2/2016    10:06:00 AM game    EF
   20          1/2/2016    10:06:00 AM game    GH
   21          1/2/2016    3:00:00 PM  game    AB
   ```

In some cases, there is a single bid made by one bidder for a particular product and no other bids for that product that occur close in time (e.g., observation #21). In most cases, however, there are several bids from several bidders for the same product that are close together in time (e.g., observations 1-4 make up a group; observations 14-16 make up a group). To study these groups, I need to be able to group them and identify each group with a unique identifier. Ultimately, I also need to be able to count both the total number of bids in each group and the number of unique/distinct bidders in each group. That's something I can probably solve on my own if I figure out how to create the groups, but I mention it in case there is a simpler/more integrated approach to that.

What I'm struggling with is the "close in time" parameter. If, "close in time" meant the same day, it's clear to me that I could use id in plyr and create a new column ("bidgrp") (or any of several other approaches). Something like:

```
bids$bidgrp <- id(bids[c("date", "product")], drop = TRUE)
```

But, "close in time" actually means within 5 minutes. In other words, for example, observations 9, 11, and 12 are part of a group, but 10 - since it is more than 5 minutes after the earliest member of the group (9), is not part of the group. Part of the challenge is figuring how to establish what the first (earliest) member of the group is (I don't have a reliable indicator, so [this] ([Grouping observations based on first row value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978438/grouping-observations-based-on-first-row-value)) solution won't work, but that can probably be done by sorting the data before attempting any grouping (although here again, if there are smarter, more efficient ways to do this, I'd welcome them)

From looking at other conditional grouping questions on SO and elsewhere, my instinct is to tackle this with a series of ifelse loop-like steps as follows:

1. Sort the dataset first by date, then by product, then by time
2. Assign a group id number of i to the first observation
3. Look at the product being bid on in next observation; if it is a bid for a different product than the product in the prior observation, assign it a group id of i+1; if it is a bid for the same product, look at the date.
4. If the date is different than the prior observation, assign it a group id of i+1; if it is the same date, look at the time
5. If the time is more than 5 minutes after the prior observation, assign it a group id of i+1; if it is within 5 minutes of the *earliest observation in the group* (this is what makes the problem particularly tricky - not just a matter of looking at the last observation, but knowing which observation to key off when determining distance in time), assign it a group number of i and look at the next observation

The result (for the sample data above), would identify 9 groups, as follows:

```
observation date    time        product bidder  grpid
1       1/1/2016    9:00:00 AM  book    AB      1
2       1/1/2016    9:01:00 AM  book    CD      1
3       1/1/2016    9:02:00 AM  book    EF      1
4       1/1/2016    9:03:00 AM  book    CD      1
5       1/1/2016    9:00:00 AM  game    AB      2
6       1/1/2016    9:01:00 AM  game    CD      2
7       1/1/2016    9:02:00 AM  game    CD      2
8       1/1/2016    9:07:00 AM  game    CD      3
9       1/2/2016    9:00:00 AM  book    AB      4
11      1/2/2016    9:02:00 AM  book    EF      4
12      1/2/2016    9:03:00 AM  book    EF      4
10      1/2/2016    9:06:00 AM  book    CD      5
14      1/2/2016    8:59:00 AM  game    CD      6
13      1/2/2016    9:00:00 AM  game    EF      6
15      1/2/2016    9:00:00 AM  game    GH      6
16      1/2/2016    9:01:00 AM  game    AB      6
17      1/2/2016    10:00:00 AM game    AB      7
18      1/2/2016    10:06:00 AM game    CD      8
19      1/2/2016    10:06:00 AM game    EF      8
20      1/2/2016    10:06:00 AM game    GH      8
21      1/2/2016    3:00:00 PM  game    AB      9
```

And, I'll ultimately need to get to something like this:

```
grpid   bids    uniquebidders
1       4       3
2       3       2
3       1       1
4       3       2
5       1       1
6       4       4
7       1       1
8       3       3
9       1       1
```

Apologies for the long question. I know several of the sub-issues here (working with time; loop-like operations) have been covered on SO (I've reviewed many of them), but it's the combination of these issues that makes this particularly challenging for me (and hopefully useful for others).

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: When you said *4.If the date is different than the prior observation, assign it a group id of i+1; if it is the same date, look at the time 5. If the time is more than 5 minutes after the prior observation, assign it a group id of i+1*, why observation 10 is in group 6? It is just 3 minutes after the prior. 
Do you mean less than 5 minutes difference from earliest in current group?

Comment: Yes @Titolondon. Very good catch. My apologies. It's exactly this need to not just look back to the prior observation but to be able to reference the earliest of member of the group that the current observation may be a member of that makes this particularly hard for me! My apologies. I've edited the question to be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a specific function for date-time comparaison. I do know if it is performant for 5 millions rows but it work on the example dataset. I followed your steps. It use `rleid` that create a run-length type id column. Using it twice, you get the group id you want. It deliberatly goes step by step but it could be written more concisely.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

# this function compare each datetime of the vector with the first one
# If > 5 mins then a new time reference is set for next group and group 
# is incremented
func_perso <- function(vec){
  time1 <- vec[1]
  grp <- 1
  res <- vector("integer", length(vec))
  for(i in 1:length(vec)){
    time <- vec[i]
    if(difftime(time, time1, units = "secs") > 5*60){
      grp <- grp + 1
      time1 <- time
    }
    res[i] <- grp
  }
  res
}

# Create a datetime object (POSIXct) for easier comparaison
DT[, dtime := as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(date, time), "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "UTC"))]
# order data as you mentionned
setorder(DT, date, product, dtime)
# Apply func on column dtime by data and product
DT[, grp1 := .SD[, func_perso(dtime)], by = .(date, product)]
# use rleid to count identify the group
DT[, grp2 := paste0(product, rleid(grp1)), by = .(date, product)]
# count the group
DT[, grpid := rleid(grp2)]
# delete non necessary column
DT[, `:=`(
  dtime = NULL, 
  grp1 = NULL, 
  grp2 = NULL
)]
# the result
DT
#>     Observation     date        time product bidder grpid
#>  1:           1 1/1/2016  9:00:00 AM    book     AB     1
#>  2:           2 1/1/2016  9:01:00 AM    book     CD     1
#>  3:           3 1/1/2016  9:02:00 AM    book     EF     1
#>  4:           4 1/1/2016  9:03:00 AM    book     CD     1
#>  5:           5 1/1/2016  9:00:00 AM    game     AB     2
#>  6:           6 1/1/2016  9:01:00 AM    game     CD     2
#>  7:           7 1/1/2016  9:02:00 AM    game     CD     2
#>  8:           8 1/1/2016  9:07:00 AM    game     CD     3
#>  9:           9 1/2/2016  9:00:00 AM    book     AB     4
#> 10:          11 1/2/2016  9:02:00 AM    book     EF     4
#> 11:          12 1/2/2016  9:03:00 AM    book     EF     4
#> 12:          10 1/2/2016  9:06:00 AM    book     CD     5
#> 13:          14 1/2/2016  8:59:00 AM    game     CD     6
#> 14:          13 1/2/2016  9:00:00 AM    game     EF     6
#> 15:          15 1/2/2016  9:00:00 AM    game     GH     6
#> 16:          16 1/2/2016  9:01:00 AM    game     AB     6
#> 17:          17 1/2/2016 10:00:00 AM    game     AB     7
#> 18:          18 1/2/2016 10:06:00 AM    game     CD     8
#> 19:          19 1/2/2016 10:06:00 AM    game     EF     8
#> 20:          20 1/2/2016 10:06:00 AM    game     GH     8
#> 21:          21 1/2/2016  3:00:00 PM    game     AB     9
#>     Observation     date        time product bidder grpid
```

Comment: Thank you, Titolondon. I (mostly) understand your approach, but need to work through it a bit more. I am getting an error when I try to apply the function on the dtime column: `Error in `[.data.frame`(DT, , `:=`(grp1, .SD[, func_perso(datetime)]),  : 
  unused argument (by = .(date, product))`

Comment: You need to work with data.table. Your data frame must be converted to data.table. It is the purpose of setDT function in my code. Did you run the code as it is when you got the error?

Comment: Got it. My apologies. Missed that at the top. I can reproduce this and it does produce the result. I'll try running it on my larger dataset and let you know about performance. Many thanks, Titolondon. You've been a big help.

Comment: Glad I could help! Do not forget to validate my answer to close the question. ;-) hope I hear from you when you will have tried on the big dataset. I may could help on optimisation.